# How to display insecure content on a secure page

Tags: http, security, iframe, https

I want to use a flipbook iframe resource which is only available by HTTP request -
but my page is loaded over HTTPS. Chrome wont display mixed content.

I'm not able to include the resource from a different host or download and host the content on the site directly.

Is there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the file fetchdata.php on your server and try to use below code (cURL)

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
$url = $_GET['url'];
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
}`
```

then in your iframe tag, something like:

```
<iframe src="/fetchdata.php?url=http://www.flipbook-url.com/"></iframe>
```

You can also add some more validation in the same page for 404 and other errors.

Comment: this is not secure. someone can use your fetchdata side to load any content and functions he want. for instance this could be exploited for stealing cookies/session etc... (arbitrary external url is rendered under your domain)

Comment: It might be okay temporarily but this just returns a page not found anyway. Is it possible to configure this one page as an exception to loading with SSL?

Comment: @ConnorStansfield You could just only serve that particular page over HTTP, meaning the whole webpage would be HTTP, not just the iframe. That would just result in your page having a "Not Secure" warning in the address bar for that URL. This would work if your site is available over HTTP and HTTPS. It's also a better solution than trying to fool the browser into thinking it's loaded secure content when it hasn't.